# drupal 7 - restrict acces to full node

Tags: permissions, drupal-7, nodes

I have a content type called 'logos' all theses are in a grid view and output as a block.

I do not want the user to view the full node, only the view. I have tried content_access module but my grid view also disappears, is there a way to restrict access to full nodes for a specific content type?

Comment: Try the [Premium content module](http://drupal.org/project/premium_content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to not publish the node as per https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11026/how-to-restrict-direct-access-to-the-nodes-in-drupal-7

I have tested it and Views can still display data.  You may need to adjust the styles though as I find by default, Drupal adds a highlight to unpublished nodes to distinguish that it is unpublished.

Comment: that is good to know, I assumed unpublished nodes would not be available to views. I suppose I could find the hook that adds the class and add some logic based on content type to remove the class which changes the styling or do a css fix. Thanks

Comment: @welovedesign - or instead of removing the class you can override the CSS for the class so that it doesn't display any differently :)

Answer (score 0):

I just did a dirty fix in reprocess page function

```
if ($variables['node']->type == "logos") {
            drupal_goto('404');

    }
```

there must be a better way. Also what about google ignoring the node?

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify a bit. You are displaying a block view. So why do you not limit the view to the fields you want to show instead of displaying the node?

You can also use fields permissions (or cck permissions, I forgot the exact name), so specify permissions per field.

Comment: "So why do you not limit the view to the fields you want to show instead of displaying the node?" - how do this? I tried the permissions settings in views.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://www.drupal.org/project/restrict_node_page_view, it's quite simple:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_access().
 */
function MYMODULE_node_access($node, $op, $account) { 
  // Default checks
  if (!is_object($node)) {
    return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;
  }
  $type = is_string($node) ? $node : $node->type;
  if($op == 'view' && arg(0) == 'node' && arg(1) === $node->nid) {
    // Restrict access to full MYTYPE node for anon users
    if ($type == 'MYTYPE' && user_is_anonymous()) {
      return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
    }
  }
  // Default
  return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Rabbit Hole](https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) Drupal contrib module

> What is this? Rabbit Hole is a module that adds the ability to control
>   what should happen when an entity is being viewed at its own page.
>
> Perhaps you have a content type that never should be displayed on its
>   own page, like an image content type that's displayed in a carousel.
>   Rabbit Hole can prevent this node from being accessible on its own
>   page, through node/xxx.

This module will do what you have asked for:

> I do not want the user to view the full node, only the view. I have
>   tried content_access module but my grid view also disappears, is there
>   a way to restrict access to full nodes for a specific content type?

Rabbit hole is also an answer in the link in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11972825/227926) to this question.